# Передать переменные окружения внутрь контейнера

Tags: docker, openshift

Мне требуется передать переменные окружения внутрь контейнера. Делаю я это с помощью [configmaps](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.2/dev_guide/configmaps.html).

У меня не получается добавить [configmaps](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.2/dev_guide/configmaps.html) в [pod](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/architecture/core_concepts/pods_and_services.html). Следовательно, я не могу прокинуть переменные в контейнер.

Ссылки даны, возможно, на старые версии.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Вариант 1

Использовать утилиту [oc](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.5/welcome/index.html):

```
oc set env
```

`configmaps` также можно использовать в этом случае. Данный вариант представляется менее практичным и изящным. Поэтому предлагается второй вариант, который использует yml.

## Вариант 2

Следует привязать [configmap](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.2/dev_guide/configmaps.html) к [DeploymentConfig](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.2/dev_guide/deployments.html), как переменную окружения.

Детали по [ссылке](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#configure-all-key-value-pairs-in-a-configmap-as-container-environment-variables). Конфиг лежит [тут](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/website/master/content/en/examples/pods/pod-configmap-envFrom.yaml). Следует взять следующую часть конфига:

```
  envFrom:
  - configMapRef:
      name: special-config
```

и поместить её в исходный конфиг, в раздел `- kind: DeploymentConfig`, `containers`